# Suddenly lost permissions to all files

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, administrator

I'm running Windows 2008 R2. A few days ago, all my software lost permissions to do pretty much anything with files on the disk. Eclipse, LyX, and even Word, won't save files. SourceTree has trouble starting up because it can't create or alter its temporaries. I even get the "needs administrator privileges" popup when trying to move files from one place to another.

I can get any software to work properly by going to its executable and setting the Run As Administrator flag, but I really don't want to keep it that way.

This change took place when I restarted my machine, which may have happened after some sort of Windows automatic update.

What happened, and how do I fix it?

Comment: System Restore or restore from image backup

Comment: O, gods, no. This machine is not regularly maintained and I have no idea where the image backups are and how to work them. But that's not the bad part. The bad part is, if I do that, whatever happened will probably just happen again, and I'll be none the wiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João,

Can you please do the following:

- Start MMC.exe
- Add Snap-In Group Policy Object
- Then go to --> Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Local Policies --> Security Options
- Make sure that this options are like shown in **bold**

  - User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account --> **Disabled**
  - User Account Control: Behaviour of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode --> **Elevate without prompting**
  - User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode --> **Disabled**
- Close MMC
- Finally restart your computer to apply the changes

Comment: Why? How will **disabling UAC and potentially running every single piece of software as administrator** help the OP? This isn't fixing the problem, it's sweeping the problem under the rug using a nitroglycerine-coated broom.